# Filtering out observations with wrong start date in panel data

Tags: variables, filter, panel, stata

I'm working with panel data in Stata.

It is data where companies are questioned annually. I only want to analyse data of companies who were first questioned in a specific year (2010). I want to drop all entries of companies which were not first interviewed in 2010. The data is in the following form:

```
idnum year
1     2010 
1     2011
1     2012
2     2009
2     2010
2     2011
3     2011
3     2012
```

So companies may have been interviewed before in which case I want to drop them or first interviewed later in which case I also want to drop them. So in the example from the picture I would only want to keep entries for the first company (idnum =1).

I have tried the following:

```
by idnum, sort: drop if year<2010
```

However, this only drops the entries before 2010 but not all entries with that id that were questioned before 2010.

Does anyone have any ideas?

---

**EDIT:**

I feel like the way to go would be to fetch all id for companies that have not been interviewed in 2010 and drop them. and then fetch all companies from 2009 or before and drop them as well. But I don't know how that would be implemented in Stata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for your toy example:

```
clear
input idnum year
1 2010
1 2011
1 2012
2 2009
2 2010
2 2011
2 2012
3 2011
3 2012
end

bysort idnum (year): generate tag = year[1] != 2010 

list, sepby(idnum)

     +--------------------+
     | idnum   year   tag |
     |--------------------|
  1. |     1   2010     0 |
  2. |     1   2011     0 |
  3. |     1   2012     0 |
     |--------------------|
  4. |     2   2009     1 |
  5. |     2   2010     1 |
  6. |     2   2011     1 |
  7. |     2   2012     1 |
     |--------------------|
  8. |     3   2011     1 |
  9. |     3   2012     1 |
     +--------------------+
```

```
drop if tag

list

     +--------------------+
     | idnum   year   tag |
     |--------------------|
  1. |     1   2010     0 |
  2. |     1   2011     0 |
  3. |     1   2012     0 |
     +--------------------+
```

Or in one line:

```
bysort idnum (year): drop if year[1] != 2010
```